# Magento collection filter

Tags: magento

In magento collection I want to filter values using "store" attribute. I have some values in array. Based on that array I need to filter values. But both below functions are not working.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('store',array('in' => array(1,2,3)));
$collection->addFilter('store',array('in' => array(1,2,3));
```

Is there any other possibility to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('stores', array('in' => array(1,2,3)));
```

addFieldToFilter did the job :)

Comment: why you have used `'in'=>array()` twice?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the calculated sql will be like this:

```
select 'fields' from 'tablename' where stores in ('1','2','3');
```

As you can see `in` operator needs an array.